# Learning PHP I need some clarification about concat, combined operators and increment operator

Tags: php, concatenation

I almost feel stupid asking such basic question, anyway.

I just started learning php on my own by reading some books, before that I used to wander from one online tutorial to another, I should have started from the very basic but I dived head first into if else, foreach, while, arrays etc.

Despite grabbing the concept of those I now realized there are few things that confuse me.

So I was doing this simple exercise, print out the numbers from 1 to 5 using ++ and the *= multiply the power of 2.

```
$i = 1;
echo $i.'-'.++$i.'-'.++$i.'-'.++$i.'-'.++$i;
```

Seems all good here, my question is why if I echo $i now it returns 5?
Do I have to reassign the 1 to $i if I want to reuse it later?

I tried to use the same pattern to echo the powers of 2 but all I got was the first and last multiplication.

```
$p = 1;
echo $p .'-'.$p*= 2 .'-'.$p*= 2 .'-'.$p*= 2 .'-'.$p*= 2 .'-'.$p*= 2 .'-';
```

Does that mean that I cannot use concatenation if I use combined operators and I would have to echo each line?

Keep in mind I'm restricted to use what is explained in the first two chapters.

Comment: Please do not write this sort of code. It is unreadable and likely to lead to errors.

Comment: Also, we have no idea what books you are reading, so their first two chapters are a mystery to us.

Comment: You'll never use such stinky code in production. Does not even make sense and serves no clear purpose. It's not even educational. It's just doing pointless stuff to confuse beginners. Consider tossing the book.

Comment: Yes I realize it's horrible and have no real use like this, I'm supposed to use just echo or print, concatenation and combined operators, no for, while or any other function.

Yep, the way was explained or I understood it was confusing, I was gonna echo each incremental but then I wouldn't have used anything beside ++ and . 
I tried this way and go even more confused.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop.

```
$stringVar = "";
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {
    $stringVar .= "$i -";
}
echo $stringVar;
```

I'll leave the second one as an exercise for you.

Comment: I was only allowed to use echo or print and combined operators and concatenation.

Comment: ...Why?  Use the best solution for the problem.

Comment: I know, just trying to follow what the book instructed, I learned on my own to write Wordpress plugins for my needs, I wanted to improve my php skills by reading accredited books instead of free tutorials online, maybe starting from the basic would clear up some doubts I have but I find things get even more confusion for such basic things.

Like in my second example with the *= operator, it didn't output the way I thought it would, I just got 1-32, no errors or anything, so I wondered why.

Answer (score 0):

A simple variable (like your $i) stores one digit

so if you do a **++$i**, you do the same as **$i = $i +1**
that means you change the content of your variable

> $i = 1;
>   $i_originalValue = $i;
>   echo $i.'-'.++$i.'-'.++$i.'-'.++$i.'-'.++$i;
>   echo $i; //prints 5 
>   echo $i_originalValue; //prints 1

Comment: Ok so if I assigned 1 to $i and later I echo it as ++$i the next time I'm gonna use that variable it will have whatever value was last assigned to it, "doesn't matter" that I echoed it or not, the value was changed, in this case.